# HOw to read URL Params from JAVA?

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to read the browser URL using Java,im using

```
request.getRequestURI()
```

My URL is,

https://1.2.1.1:8443/om/em/Ement/nodeSummary/PSS32-94.11

im able to read only till PSS32-94
Any pointers on how to read the complete PSS32-94.11 would be needful.

JAVA Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/nodeSummary/{nodeLabel}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody NodeAlarmSummary getNodeSummary(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String nodeLabel) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String requestId = multipleRepliesFactoryImpl.createUniqueRequestId();
        ExecInfo exInfo = multipleRepliesFactoryImpl.createExecInfo(RequestMethod.GET, request.getRequestURI(), "");
        String[] targetObjects = { "Get Node Summary of " + nodeLabel };
        String reqId = multipleRepliesFactoryImpl.createStartOpMessage(session.getId(), requestId, "GET", targetObjects, exInfo);

        NodeAlarmSummary varGetNodeSummary = eqmSummary.getNodeSummary(nodeLabel, neCache);

        multipleRepliesFactoryImpl.createStopOpMessage(session.getId(), requestId, RequestStatus.Success);
        return varGetNodeSummary;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: did you try `request.getRequestURL()` ?